# WPF Extended ListBox doesn't find definition

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

have extended ListBox to give me a horizontal List Box, i.e, in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Class="Renishaw.Inspire.InTheatreCompanion.View.HorizontalListBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Style="{x:Null}">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Name="ItemContainer" 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>


</ListBox>
```

and in the code behind

```
public partial class HorizontalListBox : ListBox
   {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty IndentItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
         "IndentItems", typeof(double), typeof(HorizontalListBox), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIndentItemsChanged)));

      public HorizontalListBox()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public double IndentItems
      {
         get { return (double)GetValue(IndentItemsProperty); }
         set { SetValue(IndentItemsProperty, value); }
      }

      private static void OnIndentItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         var horizontalListBox = (HorizontalListBox)d;
         var thickness = new Thickness((double)e.NewValue, 0, 0, 0);
         horizontalListBox.ItemContainer.Margin = thickness;
      }

      public static void SetIndentItems(DependencyObject obj, double thickness)
      {
         obj.SetValue(IndentItemsProperty, thickness);
      }

      public static double GetIndentItems(DependencyObject obj)
      {
         return (double)obj.GetValue(IndentItemsProperty);
      }

   }
```

where the dependency property IndentItems is suppose to allow me to indent the items a set amount by setting the margin of the VirtualizingStackPanel used to contain the items. However, attempting to build this throws an error telling me that "HorizonatlListBox does not contain a definition for 'ItemContainer'" even though it has been given that name in the xaml. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Comment: @Clemens: Setting the margin at the HorizonatlListBox level gives different behaviour, i.e., the list box is idented and not the list items in the list box. This gives a different appearance when scrolling.

Comment: So it does! Totally missed that one. If you set that as the answer I'll mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Name of an element in a Template does not generate a member in the class that declares the Template, i.e. there is no `ItemContainer` member in your HorizontalListBox class.

Besides that, your `IndentItems` property seems to be redundant, because `ListBox` already has a `Padding` property:

```
<local:HorizontalListBox Padding="50,0,0,0" .../>
```

---

Now there is probably no more need for a derived HorizontalListBox, as you could just write this:

```
<ListBox Padding="50,0,0,0" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can meet your requirements much simpler than by creating new control:

```
<App.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalStackPanelTemplate">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
</App.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding source}" Padding ="50,0,0,0"
         ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalStackPanelTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using a converter for this?

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxMargins.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxMargins"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:StackConverter x:Key="StackConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Name="ItemContainer" 
                                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Converter={StaticResource StackConverter}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> source { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        source = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        source.Add("Test element1");
        source.Add("Test element2");
        source.Add("Test element3");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

I didn't do all the check here but in my test, the panel is indented.

```
public class StackConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool focused = (bool)value;

        if (focused)
        {
            return new Thickness(50);
        }
        else
        {
            return new Thickness(0);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I see the benefit of using a converter (there's still a hard coded thickness value in there). Ideally the indent (thickness) should be a property of the extended ListBox, hence the use of a Dependency Property.